# How to use python mysqldb to insert many rows at once

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a list of lists, e.g `[['a','b'],['c','d']]`.

I have a table called `T` and two fields `F1`, `F2`.  The first item in the field list maps to `F1`, second to `F2`.

How can I insert rows for each inner list in a single command or call, rather than using a for loop like this?

```
for i in [['a','b'],['c','d']]:
    c.execute("insert into T (F1,F2) values (%s, %s)", (i[0], i[1]))
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

From [MySQLdb User's Guide](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html):

```
c.executemany(
      """INSERT INTO breakfast (name, spam, eggs, sausage, price)
      VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""",
      [
      ("Spam and Sausage Lover's Plate", 5, 1, 8, 7.95 ),
      ("Not So Much Spam Plate", 3, 2, 0, 3.95 ),
      ("Don't Wany ANY SPAM! Plate", 0, 4, 3, 5.95 )
      ] )
```

so in your case:

```
c.executemany("insert into T (F1,F2) values (%s, %s)",
    [('a','b'),('c','d')])
```

Comment: Is this more efficient than using the mySQL build in with a some string manipulation? So that your string is "insert into T (F1,F2) values (a,b), (c,d)" and pass it to execute?

Comment: @Jochen You really don't want to do that unless you are _absolutely sure_ your data is coming from a trusted source (and I still believe "never trust the client" is a good rule to keep in all circumstances). It's generally a lot better, at least when you're working with a mature library like MySQLdb, to leave the necessary quoting/encoding/escaping to the lib rather than attempting it yourself; even if it incurs a bit of overhead, the peace of mind is worth it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work with utf8mb4 character set. It throws a strange error "unknown encoding: utf8mb4"

Comment: @Jochen **Don't** use string manipulation to include data that could potentially come from end users into a query. That is the main (if not the only) source of SQL injection vulnerabilities. Train yourself to think the opposite way: there must be a very, *very*, **very** good reason why you would build up the query with data included directly, and even then, you need to be *really, really* sure that the end user can't include SQL at all or that it will be escaped. A single subtle mistake could be the difference between your app returning an error vs. spitting back e-mails and passwords hashes.

Comment: to see the results in DB you also will have to add `c.execute("COMMIT")`.

Comment: Calling `execute()` for each row: **12.2 minutes**. Calling `executemany()` with 32 rows per query: **9.9 minutes (19% faster)**. Custom SQL code: **2.6 minutes (79% faster)**. It's not true that custom SQL code is insecure: `con.escape_string()` was made for this purpose. Heck, it's not even against untrusted input, it's also about correctly handling any apostrophes or quotes in regular input. My tests were done with 4 million rows, which was 927MB of SQL code in the custom sql code test.

Comment: @Luc: what do you mean custom SQL code? I am trying to insert code with executemany but it is so slow

Comment: @TuanDo Sorry, that wasn't very clear. I must have meant building a big query string manually, so a bunch of inserts in one query (`INSERT INTO x (col1, col2) VALUES("val1.1","val1.2"),("val2.1","val2.2"),("val3.1","val3.2");`), making it as large as a single query allows (there is a configurable limit of, by default, a few megabytes if I remember correctly). Other answers show how to do this, but they don't use `escape_string` and the code is **insecure** if you don't escape the values (or parse them as number or something) before including them in a query!

Answer (score 22):

It's possible to insert all rows in one single statement like @adamhajari, and avoid sql injections like @zenpoy, at the same time. You just need to create a big insert statement and let mysqldb's `execute` do the formatting.

```
values_to_insert = [('a','b'),('c','d')]
query = "INSERT INTO T (F1, F2) VALUES " + ",".join("(%s, %s)" for _ in values_to_insert)
flattened_values = [item for sublist in values_to_insert for item in sublist]
c.execute(query, flattened_values)
```

Not super readable, but can be slightly faster than executemany (I tried inserting batches of 50000 rows in a local DB, executemany was 20% slower).

Comment: I think some db driver cannot handle super long parameter list. eg. "pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')"

Answer (score 2):

```
def multiple_insert(cursor, table, cols, rows):
    sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO %s(%s) values %s' % (
        table,
        ','.join(cols),
        ','.join('(%s , %s)' for _ in rows)
    )
    values = [_ for r in rows for _ in r]
    cursor.execute(sql_insert, values)


# eg:
rows = [(a1 , b1),(a2 , b2),(a3 , b3)]
multiple_insert(cursor, 'your_table',('col1', 'col2'), rows)
conn.commit()
```