# Efficiently add a data structure to a database

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

How to fast add this structure to mysql table (with same col. name)? There is around 15,000 similar records, twitch here can be not set with some records all other are in all records. I work with python 2.7.9 and MySQL 5.5+

```py
print(data)
>>>[
        {
            u'account': {
                u'challenges': {u'total': 0
                },
                u'twitch': {u'name': u'lgt_justice'
                },
                u'name': u'Dawwwis'
            },
            u'character': {
                u'class': u'Witch',
                u'experience': 4250334444,
                u'level': 100,
                u'name': u'Em_Jake'
            },
            u'dead': False,
            u'online': False,
            u'rank': 1,
        },
        ...  # around 15,000 entries
    ]
```

MySQL table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `acc` (
    `challenges` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
    `twitch` VARCHAR(30) NULL ,
    `accName` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
    `charName` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
    `class` VARCHAR NOT NULL ,
    `exp` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
    `lvl` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
    `dead` BOOLEAN NOT NULL ,
    `online` BOOLEAN NOT NULL ,
    `rank` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL );
```

`challenges` -> account.challenges.total
`twitch` -> account.twitch.name (this can be not set)
`accName` -> account.name
`charName` -> character.name
`class` -> character.class
`exp` -> character.experience
`lvl` -> character.lvl
`dead` -> dead
`online` -> online
`rank` -> rank

Comment: 1. This is a tree like structure. You want more than one table.
2. Did you try anything?

Comment: provide your schema of mysql-table you want to create.. is there multiple tables you wanna create??

Answer (score 0):

create your schema create table in mysql

now use python-mysql package
and follow [How to use python mysqldb to insert many rows at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011160/how-to-use-python-mysqldb-to-insert-many-values-at-once) which illustrates how to insert large amount of data in mysql using python.