# sqlite - Inserting many values at once

Tags: python, sqlite

I have data structured as a `dictionary`, and I want to use it to feed a `database`:

```
playlists={
'user1':{'Karma Police':3.0,'Roxanne':4.0,'Sonnet':5.0,'We Will Rock You':1.0,'Song 1': 1.0},
'user2':{'Karma Police':2.0,'Roxanne':3.0,'Sonnet':2.0,'We Will Rock You':3.0,'Song 2': 1.0},
'user3':{'Karma Police':8.0,'Roxanne':1.0,'Sonnet':6.0,'We Will Rock You':4.0,'Song 3': 1.0},
'user4':{'Karma Police':5.0,'Roxanne':2.0,'Sonnet':1.0,'We Will Rock You':6.0,'Song 4': 1.0},
'user5':{'Karma Police':9.0,'Roxanne':4.0,'Sonnet':7.0,'We Will Rock You':9.0,'Song 4': 1.0}}
```

then I organize the data into separate `lists`:

```
users = [k for k in playlists.keys()]
tracks = [track for track in playlists.values()]//won't need this
track_names = [t.keys() for t in tracks]
counts = [t.values() for t in tracks]
```

and create the `database`:

```
db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')    
db = sqlite3.connect('users/playlistsdb')    
c = db.cursor()

c.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE playlists(
    id text primary key, 
    user TEXT,
    track_names TEXT,  
    count INTEGER)
''')
```

using the logic `columns = ['user', 'track_names', 'counts']`,

how do I insert all values into `playlistsdb`, all at once?

Comment: Not an answer for the question, but you can make your lists simpler with `users = list(playlists.keys())` and `tracks = list(playlists.values())`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how those lists would map to your database table, but once you have a list of tuples that represent your database rows, you can use the [executemany](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html) method.

Comment: The query should look like `INSERT INTO playlists (id, user, track_names, count) VALUES (%s, %s, %d), (%s, %s, %d), ...`. So make a query string that has as many values lists as `len(users)`, and then build a list of all the values fromthe dictionary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use python mysqldb to insert many rows at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011160/how-to-use-python-mysqldb-to-insert-many-rows-at-once)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use a nested list comprehension to build list of tuples. However, one crucial item related to your primary key, change the type to `INTEGER` since `TEXT` cannot be used to for autoincrement ids:

```
playlists={'user1':{'Karma Police':3.0,'Roxanne':4.0,'Sonnet':5.0,
                    'We Will Rock You':1.0,'Song 1': 1.0},
           'user2':{'Karma Police':2.0,'Roxanne':3.0,'Sonnet':2.0,
                    'We Will Rock You':3.0,'Song 2': 1.0},
           'user3':{'Karma Police':8.0,'Roxanne':1.0,'Sonnet':6.0,
                    'We Will Rock You':4.0,'Song 3': 1.0},
           'user4':{'Karma Police':5.0,'Roxanne':2.0,'Sonnet':1.0,
                    'We Will Rock You':6.0,'Song 4': 1.0},
           'user5':{'Karma Police':9.0,'Roxanne':4.0,'Sonnet':7.0,
                    'We Will Rock You':9.0,'Song 4': 1.0}}

sqltuples = [(k1, k2, v2) for k1, v1 in playlists.items() for k2, v2 in v1.items()]

c = db.cursor()

c.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE playlists(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    user TEXT,
    track_names TEXT,  
    count INTEGER)
''')
db.commit()

c.executemany('INSERT INTO playlists (user, track_names, count) VALUES (?,?,?)', sqltuples)
db.commit()
```

**Output**

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM playlists;")
for row in c.fetchall():
    print(row)

# (1, 'user1', 'Sonnet', 5)
# (2, 'user1', 'Roxanne', 4)
# (3, 'user1', 'Karma Police', 3)
# (4, 'user1', 'Song 1', 1)
# (5, 'user1', 'We Will Rock You', 1)
# (6, 'user5', 'Sonnet', 7)
# (7, 'user5', 'Song 4', 1)
# (8, 'user5', 'Roxanne', 4)
# (9, 'user5', 'Karma Police', 9)
# (10, 'user5', 'We Will Rock You', 9)
# (11, 'user4', 'Sonnet', 1)
# (12, 'user4', 'Song 4', 1)
# (13, 'user4', 'Roxanne', 2)
# (14, 'user4', 'Karma Police', 5)
# (15, 'user4', 'We Will Rock You', 6)
# (16, 'user2', 'Sonnet', 2)
# (17, 'user2', 'Song 2', 1)
# (18, 'user2', 'Roxanne', 3)
# (19, 'user2', 'Karma Police', 2)
# (20, 'user2', 'We Will Rock You', 3)
# (21, 'user3', 'Sonnet', 6)
# (22, 'user3', 'Roxanne', 1)
# (23, 'user3', 'Karma Police', 8)
# (24, 'user3', 'Song 3', 1)
# (25, 'user3', 'We Will Rock You', 4)
```